# Is Entity-Attribute-Value pattern the right approach to model this data?

Tags: sql, sqlite, entity-attribute-value, datamodel

To control the experimental setup user inputs the following table which defines unique parameter configurations, i.e. combinations of parameter values under which the experiments should be run. The amount of parameters and their meaning can be arbitrary, here, for instance, we've got `Mode`, `AmpGain` and `InputVoltage`.

| ConfigName | Mode | AmpGain | InputVoltage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MX1_LG_HV | MX1 | 1 | 3.3 |
| MX1_HG_HV | MX1 | 10 | 3.3 |
| MX2_LG_HV | MX2 | 1 | 3.3 |
| MX2_HG_HV | MX2 | 10 | 3.3 |
| MX2_LG_LV | MX2 | 1 | 1.8 |
| MX2_HG_LV | MX2 | 10 | 1.8 |

In my application this data needs to be saved in the SQL-like database (e.g. SqLite).
From various articles on database design patterns I found out *Entity-Attribute-Value Pattern* is a possible approach to represent this model, namely:

`Parameter` table to describe the parameters

| ParamID (PK) | ParamName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Mode |
| 2 | AmpGain |
| 3 | InputVoltage |

`Config` table to describe the configurations

| ConfigID (PK) | ConfigName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | MX1_LG_HV |
| 2 | MX1_HG_HV |
| 3 | MX2_LG_HV |
| 4 | MX2_HG_HV |
| 5 | MX2_LG_LV |
| 6 | MX2_HG_LV |

Finally, the table combining the relationship, where `ConfigID` and `ParamID` form a Primary Key:

| ConfigID | ParamID | ValueInt | ValueFloat | ValueStr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | NULL | MX1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | NULL | 3.3 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL | MX1 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 3 | NULL | 3.3 | NULL |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | NULL | MX2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 3 | NULL | 3.3 | NULL |
| 4 | 1 | NULL | NULL | MX2 |
| 4 | 2 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 3 | NULL | 3.3 | NULL |
| 5 | 1 | NULL | NULL | MX2 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | 3 | NULL | 1.8 | NULL |
| 6 | 1 | NULL | NULL | MX2 |
| 6 | 2 | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | 3 | NULL | 1.8 | NULL |

It this the right way to implement the EAV Pattern?
Is there any better way to model that data considering there won't be more than 25-30 parameters and this data needs to be accessed/saved only once per minute?

Comment: EAV is an antipattern, ie bad idea, no matter what. You lose type safety, the ability to check, index and even query values. To retrieve a single thing you have to perform an N-way self join or rebuild rows on the client. If you want to store a bunch of stuff you don't need to query, store it as JSON or XML text. SQLite has [JSON functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) that can be used to extract information from JSON fields.

Comment: Should you decide you need to query some of the JSON fields you can use JSON functions to create computed columns. You can include these columns in indexes too, speeding up queries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for pointing out at JSON support by SQLite! Unfortunately my application requires querying on these attributes.

Comment: I can't see why you should not be better off creating a 20-to-30 column table with all parameters, nullable, side by side, even adding a unique index over all 20 to 30 columns, if you want the database to ensure the uniqueness of the combinations. You help the RDBMS do what it's good at: enforce correct data types at the atomic level, and uniqueness at row level. I would not add any complexity without being able to describe in detail the advantages I expect out of it. Form follows function, and simplicity does it, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @marcothesane do you mean naming columns after parameters directly as it is shown in the first (input) table in my post? I thought it's a bad practice. Also parameter names may contain white spaces.

Comment: The classical way of naming parameters that contain anything else than alphabetic letters, digits or underscores would be to replace the offending characters with underscores. You can always put them into double quotes to keep them exactly as the original, but that is not elegant when writing queries. And why should it be a bad practice to model a table in order to be performant and get quality assertion for free from the database? Yes, you have to commit to a structure. But you can always add columns if new parameters come along ...

Comment: @marcothesane you are right Marco. But like I said in the post, the amount of parameters/columns and respective datatypes can be arbitrary. This complicates when accessing database by means of ORM model (C#, EntityFramework). In a normal way I would do ALTER to construct table columns each time new parameters config has been entered.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to store these parameters serialized into a JSON field, as it has been suggested by @Panagiotis Kanavos. This is far less hassle than implementing EAV pattern, plus, many ORM frameworks support accessing JSON field.